# Undefined reference to sqrt

Tags: c, makefile, sqrt

I have included `math.h` in `1.c` and `LDLIBS=-lm` in the `makefile`.

1.c and 2.c are some of the files in current directory.

Make file is as follows:

```
dINES+=PROJECT_CONF_H=\"project-conf.h\"
CONTIKI_PROJECT = 1 2
all: $(CONTIKI_PROJECT)

CONTIKI = ../..

WITH_UIP6=1
UIP_CONF_IPV6=1

CFLAGS+= -DUIP_CONF_IPV6_RPL -DUIP_CONF_IPV6 -DWITH_UIP6
LDLIBS=-lm
ifdef PERIOD
CFLAGS=-DPERIOD=$(PERIOD)
endif    

include $(CONTIKI)/Makefile.include
```

I have read related stackoverflow question and answers but unable to understand why `Undefined reference to  sqrt`.

Comment: Try a dry run `make -n`. It should tell you right away if the executed commands aren't what you expect

Comment: When stuff like this happens even though you have included math.h, you are likely not linking the floating point library to the project. Common problem with embedded systems. Usually there's some option for this when you create the project, or otherwise there's some compiler/linker option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, notice that `include $(CONTIKI)/Makefile.include` could unset any settings you have made above. So we cannot debug your problem.

Then, run `make -p` once to understand the builtin rules (assuming you are using [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)). Be sure to read [documentation of `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html). Run also `make --trace` and/or use [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) (e.g. as `remake -x`) to debug your `Makefile`.

Be aware that the order of program arguments to `gcc` matters a lot. Read first the [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) chapter of the documentation of `gcc`. You want to compile with `-Wall -g` (to get all warnings & debug info) which might be added to your `CFLAGS+=` line. Perhaps your 
 `CFLAGS=-DPERIOD=$(PERIOD)` line should be `CFLAGS+= -DPERIOD=$(PERIOD)`

Perhaps your `LDLIBS=-lm` line should be `LIBES= -lm`.

The `Undefined reference: sqrt` message might be because your compilation command (run by `make`) has `-lm` missing or in the wrong order.

Comment: You were right. I added `-lm` in Makefile.include. I got some other errors but got rid of this one. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you should mess your  `$(CONTIKI)/Makefile.include`

Comment: You need to understand more your particular program, GNU make, and Contiki.

Comment: Yes I will study them too. Thanks! It feels good to have help from experienced and co-operative people like you. The thing I liked is people here don't just give away a fish to satisfy hunger, instead they help us learn how to catch fish on our own.

Comment: Add to Makefile `TARGET_LIBFILES+=-lm` is a better solution.